# MySQL Finding Number of Elapsed Weeks in Current Month

Tags: mysql

**QUESTION**

Is it possible the find the number of weeks in the current month using a MySQL query?

If you answer the above question, then you have answered my question. However, I have been downvoted before for not including context, so....

**BACKGROUND (Warning: It Will Confuse You)**
*I advise not reading any further*

Because of a MySQL parser we have written in an application, my hands are tied with the way in which I must approach writing queries.

Here's the scenario:

I need to average out the number of hours worked per week over the course of a month by an employee; however, I must approach this by generating a column returned by the query that can then be summed to give me the average (yes, that is a mouth full).

Here is what I mean (and one attempt):

```
SELECT ets.*, (ets.hours/4) AS AVG_HOURS 
FROM employee_timesheet AS ets 
WHERE ets.date_worked >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Yes, the `WHERE` clause is not accurate, that will have to change, too (but that is the next step).

The application then `SUMS(avg_hours)`. Consider that each `ets` record contains the hours worked per day, by dividing the (*hours worked each day*) `/` by the (*floating representation of the number of weeks in the month*), I should then get the average worked per week over the course of the month by summing the result of the division.

To represent the *logic* in pseudo-code:

`SUM(days_hours/number_of_weeks)`

Comment: Wouldn't the pseudo-code be `SUM(days_hours)/number_of_weeks`?

Comment: @BobKaufman *Normally*, yes, it would be. My life would be great if thinking like a developer - or a normal person - were allowed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DATEDIFF function

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-10-30','2014-12-29') AS DiffDate
```

it should return the days between two date

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, yes you can find the number of weeks from a month by using SQL's

```
datepart(week, date).
```

If you need the current month's number of weeks you can do

```
Datepart(week, getdate())
```

Here's more information for [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

To get the first day of the month you can use

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @mydate), 0)
```

Comment: This is a great answer; unfortunately `DATEPART` is SQL

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it. If I want to get the current number of weeks elapsed in the current month, I can:

```
DAYOFMONTH(CURRENTDATE()) / 7
```